# I can't see the output of postgresql database access program

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

```
def bul():

    global entry_bul
    pencere = Toplevel()

    etiket= Label(pencere,text="\n# Which record do you want to find?Please enter the Student ID number.\n")
    etiket.pack()

    entry_bul=Entry(pencere)
    entry_bul.pack()

    btn = Button(pencere,text="Find the student",bg="orange",fg="navy",command=sorgula)
    btn.pack()

def sorgula():

    conn = connect(database="dorm", user="postgres", password="605394", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
    print "Opened database successfully"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pers_info, school_info, room_info WHERE ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),));
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],row[4]

    print "Operation done successfully";
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

These functions run without error. But it does not give the output of the for loop on the screen.
The results on the screen are:

```
Opened database successfully
Operation done successfully
```

Comment: did you enter the data with similar code? then it would be no surprise that there is no data: you do not call `conn.commit`; calling a function is done with `()`: `conn.commit()`. and there is no need for a commit if you only read from a db.

Comment: Use a better title - "I can't see the output" is not very useful to potential answers.

Comment: I fixed the commit() but it is stil doing the same. I think "WHERE ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),)" part has a problem. It is like it doesnt see the entry_bul.get()

Comment: And also I tried with a similar and basic code. it works. As I said iI think t is related with "ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),));" part.

Comment: what is this doing? `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pers_info, school_info, room_info WHERE ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),));`

Comment: at the "bul" function there is a window which I write "Student ID num". and then at the "sorgula" function it searches for that record. and the "cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pers_info, school_info, room_info WHERE ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),)); " line sends to postgresql database and runs the statement in execute.

Comment: BTW your query looks strange a bit: `... FROM pers_info, school_info, room_info` - it is cartesian join but when any table in the list is empty, the whole result is empty too.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but there is no empty table or even a cell

Answer (score 0):

Based on the blank line between "Opened database successfully" and "Operation done successfully," I would assume that the print statement in the for loop is only running once, and that there are no values in the first and only row.

Comment: actually there is no blank line it is like

Comment: @SerdarDarende That's actually really helpful then for debugging.  That means your for loop isn't running, so I would check to make sure your "rows" variable is being populated.  Hope this helps and keep me updated

Comment: I checked out that but no change. I think the problem is in the "ID_num = (%s) ;", (entry_bul.get(),)" but I couldnt get the problem.

Comment: Try saving that SQL statement to a variables, then print it and pass it to curr.execute().  That'll help you start tracing it back to see if that string is what you intend it to be

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that as a solution, but a way to debug.  Is the string what you expect it to be?